# Python: How can I change ip address every some minute from a pool of addresses on a debian server?

Tags: python, http, ip

I am writing a code to get Google Pagerank for a list of domains. After time and certain amount of queries my ips got blacklisted and now I am getting HTTP Error 403. My question is how can I add to my script to change the ip address every some seconds from the pool of ips that  I have on the measurement server that I am using. Can anybody help?

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
import sys
import urllib.request as _urlib1  # py3 
import urllib.parse as _urlib2  # py 3

def get_pagerank(url):
    hsh = check_hash(hash_url(url))
    gurl = 'http://toolbarqueries.google.com/tbr?client=navclient-auto&features=Rank&ch=%s&q=info:%s' % (hsh, _urlib2.quote(url))
    u = _urlib1.urlopen(gurl)
    s = u.read().decode('utf-8')  # for py2, comment .decode() part
    #print(s)  # debug - response of server
    rank = s.strip()[9:]
    if rank == '':
        rank = 'None'
    if rank == 'None':
        rank = 'None'
    return rank
```

Here is my code:

Comment: you can change the IP address of your machine. It can be done by script depending of your OS

Comment: @GerardRozsavolgyi This is a measurement server that has a pool of ips. I do not want to run the script on my machine but on the debian server. Do you know how can do it with python?

Comment: for one interface eth0 : sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo ifconfig eth0 newAdress
sudo ifconfig eth0 up You have to launch that as commands from python

Comment: @GerardRozsavolgyi Thanks. can you post it as an answer? I can also vote on it?

Comment: @Mee  that is not going to automatically get a new address

Comment: @PadraicCunningham then How can I assign it in a way that ip addresses automatically change after some time?

Comment: do you control the dhcp server?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No. The ips are static ips that are assigned to us

Comment: try `sudo dhclient -r interface`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69216/discussion-between-mee-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux and for one interface eth0 :

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo ifconfig eth0 newAdress
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

You have to launch that as commands from python, changing in turn newAdress from your list of available IPs

You can run your command with :

```
from subprocess import call
subprocess.call(["command", "arg1", "arg2"])
```

For doing that at periodic time , use a thread or [celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)

Comment: but this you mean I have you do it manually every time? What do you mean by run it as commands?

Comment: launch this command from python every minute or something like that

Comment: Thanks but I do not know how to do that, can u put it here in the code?